# Finding average speed of a driver

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I was asked this question by a friend.

> Ann leaves Town A and drives towards Town B while Leslie simultaneously leaves Town B and drives towards Town A. They travel on the same route and, after passing each other on the way, Ann takes 4 hours to reach her destination, while Leslie takes 9 hours to reach her destination. If the average speed of Ann's car is 48 miles per hour, what is the average speed of Leslie's car, in miles per hour?

I am not good with these types of questions and I tried my best. I tried to use $d=rt$ but couldn't incorporate the times for different portions of the trip together.

How can I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of times for both people must be the same for the sections of the journey. If we assign t to the time it took for both Ann and Leslie to complete the first part, then:

$\frac{4}{t} = \frac{t}{9}$

$t^2 = 36$

$t = 6$ hours

So Leslie took 6 hours to travel $4\cdot 48 = 192$ miles

Leslie's speed is therefore $\frac{192}{6} = 32$ mph

Answer (score 0):

So we have that both travel the same distance. Let $v_A$ be Anna's average speed and $v_L$ Lesslie's average speed. Let's denote the distance with $s$ and the whole time taken for Lesslie to reach her destination be $t$ then we have:
$$tv_L = s$$
$$(t-5)v_A = s$$
and for the time taken for them to meet each other we have:
$$ (t-9)(v_A + v_L) = s$$
Solve the system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

Let Ann's position be $d_A$, and Leslie's position be $d_B$. Further, let's measure distance relative to town A, and say that the distance to town B is $D$. Since they're travelling at different, but constant, speeds, we can write the following:

$d_A = v_A t \\
d_L = D - v_L t$

Notice that I've arranged Leslie's position so that at $t = 0$ she's in town B.

At some time $t = t_0$, $d_A = d_L$ (i.e. their positions are the same) - in other words, $v_A t_0 = D - v_L t_0$. Then, 4 hours later Ann reaches town B, meaning:

$v_A (t_0 + 4) = D$

And 9 hours later, Leslie reaches town A, meaning:

$D - v_L (t_0 + 9) = 0$

So we have three equations to work with:

$(v_A + v_L) t_0 = D \\
v_A (t_0 + 4) = D \\
v_L (t_0 + 9) = D$

You can eliminate $D$ and $t_0$ across the equations, letting you express $v_L$ in terms of $v_A$, which we've been told is 48.

Answer (score 0):

A way to consider this type of problem while you are still grappling with the basics of algebra is to just consider it logically as follows:

You know how long it takes Leslie to complete her journey, so if you **knew** how far her journey was, you would have an answer immediately. Averagespeed = distance/time

You **know** how long it took Ann to complete her journey, and you **know** her average speed, so you **can** calculate the distance of her journey. Distance = Averagespeed*time

You **know** the two journeys were over the same distance as A to B distance must equal B to A distance. So now, **knowing** Ann's journey distance, you **know** Leslie's journey distance.

So finally, you have both **distance** and **time** for Leslie and can immediately calculate the average speed of her journey (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

Leslie drive at speed $v_1.$  Anne drives at speed $v_2 = 48 \frac {mi}{h}$

Suppose $t$ hours pass from the time of departure to the time of meeting.

In that time Anne covers $v_2t$ miles and Leslie covers $v_1t$ miles.

over the rest of the journey each covers the distance that the other traveled and the times are given.

$\frac {v_1t}{v_2} = 4$ and $\frac {v_2t}{v_1} = 9$

Yow we can cross cross multiply each plug $v_2 = 48$ and sustitue from one equation to the other.

But I think would be more fun to divide one by the other.

$\dfrac {\frac {v_1t}{v_2}}{\frac {v_2t}{v_1}} = \frac {4}{9}\\
\frac {v_1^2}{v_2^2} = \frac 49\\
v_1 = \frac 23 v_2$